# Executing each Object in a seperate thread in C++ using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the two classes as shown below

```
class CommandChannel
{
private:
    std::thread cChannelThread;
public:
    CommandChannel();
    ~CommandChannel();

    void start_comm_channel(int port, std::string ip);

    int myfunction(int a, int b);
    double otherfunction(std::string test);

    void stop_comm_channel();
};


class EventChannel
{
private:
    std::thread evChannelThread;
public:
    EventChannel();
    ~EventChannel();

    void start_ev_chnl(int port, std::string ip);

    int evFunction(int a, int b);
    double anotherfunction(std::string othertest);

    void stop_ev_chnl();
};
```

I want to expose the public functions to a user in such a way that whenever the user calls the functions from the class `CommandChannel` they are run in one thread say `cChannelThread`. And whenever the user invokes a function from the class `EventChannel` they are run in the other thread that is `evChannelThread`. 
I am not sure whether this is a good idea, but I am new to C++ particularly new to multi-threading. The basic idea is to keep the `EventChannel` class completely in another thread than the `CommandChannel` class.
P.S This question is a rephrased version of a question I previously asked which was put on hold. I hope this time its more clear.

Comment: This is probably too broad for this site tbh. I think you will probably need some kind of queueing mechanism to feed the function call requests to the running thread for each class. Also some means to synchronize the results of each invocation? (`std::promise`/`std::future`)?

Comment: BTW,  you can have multiple *objects* of the same class. So what about calls to two separate objects of the same class? Run them in just one thread for the whole class or one thread per *object* of the class?

Comment: @Galik, Yes, each object should have a separate class. There will be a limit of course as to how many objects would be possible to create. But I want to get the idea of how to achieve such kind of multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to expose the public functions to a user in such a way that whenever the user calls the functions from the class `CommandChannel` they are run in one thread say `cChannelThread`

In this case you need to forward the call to another thread. This can be done by saving the function-pointer/lambda with copies of all call arguments into a `std::function<void()>` object, passing that object to another thread, and invoking that object.

If your functions return something else then `void` then you need a mechanism to pass the return value back to the calling thread. There are more than one way to do it, you could start with using [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task).

For passing objects between threads use an atomic queue, such as [Intel Concurrent Queue Classes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506081).

Be careful when sharing objects between threads. If an object is shared between threads and at least one thread modifies the object then locking is required to prevent race conditions.